# show $(k\:\:k+1)$ generates $(1\:\:x)$

Tags: group-theory, permutations, symmetric-groups, cyclic-groups, permutation-cycles

Show $A=\{(k\:\: k+1), 1≤ k<n\}$ generates $B=\{(1\:\:x), 1<x≤ n\},$ where $B$ is a minimal generating sets for $S_n$.

So I want to show $(k\:\:k+1)$ generates $(1\:\:x)$. I want to use induction for this but I'm not sure how to put it together because I'm a bit confused on how generating sets work for transpositions and $S_n$. For this, I think I need just $n-1$ transpositions.

I have this identity and I'm not sure if it helps: $(a\:b) = (1\:a)(1\:b)(1\:a)$

Here's what I'm thinking so far, no idea if I'm on the right track or if it's right so far:

$A=\{(k\:\:k+1), k=1,\ldots,n-1\} =$ {$(1\: 2),(2\: 3),(3\: 4),\ldots,(n-2\:\:\:\:n-1)$}

Let  $n\ge 2$, so base case is $n=2$...

I'm not really sure if it's $n\ge2$, I thought it might be $n\ge3$ maybe?

Comment: Hi @eddie, what do you mean by a set generating another (and not a set generating a group)? if you know that A is a generating set of the group Sₙ, you can generate from A every element of Sₙ, so you can generate the elements of B as well. are you looking for a formula?

Comment: @UdiFogiel I want to show that you can get $B=(1\:\:x)$ from $A=${$(k\:\: k+1), 1≤ k<n$} by doing induction on $x$. So I'm looking for a way to derive $B$ from $A$ using induction. Basically, I want to show that since $A$ generates $B$, and $B$ generates $S_n$, $A$ also generates $S_n$.

Comment: a solution without an induction is applicable? and a solution that shows that A generating Sₙ is suffice as well?

Comment: @UdiFogiel I guess it can be done without induction, but I was encouraged to use induction on $x$ for this question.

Comment: Please use, for example, `$\{ x\}$` for $\{ x\}$. You have been introduced to this before. On another note: use `$\le$` for $\le$.

Comment: @Shaun sorry, I didn't know it made a difference but if it does, I'll start using it.

Comment: I changed $A=${$(k\:\: k+1), 1≤ k<n$} to $A=\{(k\:\: k+1), 1≤ k<n\}.$ The former has font mismatches and lacks proper spacing. Just one pair of dollar signs surrounds it. Thus: $$ A=\{(k\:\: k+1), 1≤ k<n\} $$

Comment: @eddie After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: @JoseAvilez thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's proof the claim with induction on $x$ for $1<x\le n$. because $x>1$ the base case is $x=2$, in this case $(1\;x)=(1\;2)\in A\subset\langle A\rangle$ as desired. now let us assume the claim is true for $1\le x-1<n$ and prove it for $x$. we will use the fact that

$$   
(1\;x)=(x-1\;\;x)(1\;\;x-1)(x-1\;\;x)
$$

this equality holds because we can compute for $1,x,x-1$ an get
$$
\begin{align}
(x-1\;\;x)(1\;\;x-1)(x-1\;\;x)(x)=&(x-1\;\;x)(1\;\;x-1)(x-1)=(x-1\;\;x)(1)=1\\
(x-1\;\;x)(1\;\;x-1)(x-1\;\;x)(x-1)=&(x-1\;\;x)(1\;\;x-1)(x)=(x-1\;\;x)(x)=x-1\\
(x-1\;\;x)(1\;\;x-1)(x-1\;\;x)(1)=&(x-1\;\;x)(1\;\;x-1)(1)=(x-1\;\;x)(x-1)=x
\end{align}
$$
and every other element is fixed by this permutation.
because $(x-1\;\;x)\in A$ and by the induction hypothesis $(1\;\;x-1)\in \langle A\rangle$ we will conclude that $(1\;\;x)\in \langle A\rangle$ as wanted.